# Text automation

Tags: text, automation

I'd like to know of a way to automate the adding and removing of text strings on an expanding list.

**As an example:**

**Rule 1 - Group 1**
user.isMemberOfGroup("n0m2pr90t0ig") && !isMemberOfAnyGroup("a457v3pa4emd", "ok12a5aatcu3")

**Rule 2 - Group 2**
user.isMemberOfGroup("a457v3pa4emd") && !isMemberOfAnyGroup("n0m2pr90t0ig", "ok12a5aatcu3")

**Rule 3 - Group 3**
user.isMemberOfGroup("ok12a5aatcu3") && !isMemberOfAnyGroup("a457v3pa4emd", "n0m2pr90t0ig")

The first rule states that if a user is part of Group 1 that it cannot be in Group 2 and Group 3

The second rule states that if a user is part of Group 2 that it cannot be in Group 1 and Group 3

The third rule states that if a user is part of Group 3 that it cannot be in Group 1 and Group 2

I would need to be able to expand to this list in text form that if I were to add Rule 4 for the fourth group, it would have to look at the positive condition group ID and add it to Rule 1, 2 and 3 negative conditions as I expand the list further.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.